# Oracle delimited column(s) into multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for an oracle query which will convert delimited columns (2 columns into multiple rows and joins it with another table

### Table1

```
id  - col1     - col2                                            
1   - PC1,PC2  - F1,F2
```

### Table2

```
 co1  - co2
 F1   - V1
 F2   - V2
```

I am looking for results

```
1,PC1,F1,V1   
1,PC1,F2,V2
1,PC2,F1,V1
1,PC2,F2,V2
```

I have tried with

```
with EXTED as (SELECT id,col1,trim(COLUMN_VALUE) col2
FROM Table1,
  xmltable(('"'
  || REPLACE(col2, ',', '","')
 || '"'))) select  FG.id,FG.col2,
 trim(COLUMN_VALUE) col2,VF.co2 from EXTED FG ,Table2 VF,
 xmltable(('"'
  || REPLACE(col2, ',', '","')
 || '"'))
 where FG.col2 = VF.col1
```

But this is taking lot of time to give results. Is there any better way to get the results ..?

Comment: Perhaps, by avoiding XML operations and splitting the strings with standard hierarchical queries; but performance will be poor regardless. The problem is not the query, but the data model, which violates the most basic requirement of sound table design - the famous "First Normal Form". Single fields should never contain more than **one** value. Comma-separated values in a single field is the most common reason students fail the first quiz in Database classes (or if it isn't, it should be). Slow performance is only one of the many very good reasons why First Normal Form matters.

Comment: yes , but its legacy data model (created 25 years back) .. we are not allowed to change it.

Comment: I am not criticizing you in any way - I am just helping you explain to your client (or bosses) why you will not be able to write a "fast" query on this model.

Comment: Sure, thank you .. before going back I wanted to make sure there is no other way to improve the query .. (data size is very less one table has 12K and second table has 4K records) - Total results from my query is around 40K records , and its taking around a minute to give back the results.

Answer (score 2):

Your query could be written as:

```
SELECT id,
       x1.COLUMN_VALUE.getStringVal() AS col1,
       x2.COLUMN_VALUE.getStringVal() AS col2,
       t2.col2
FROM   Table1 t1
       CROSS JOIN
       xmltable( ('"'|| REPLACE(t1.col1, ',', '","')|| '"') ) x1
       CROSS JOIN
       xmltable( ('"'|| REPLACE(t1.col2, ',', '","')|| '"') ) x2
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t2
       ON ( x2.COLUMN_VALUE.getStringVal() = t2.col1 );
```

**Alternately**

You could use a simple function:

```
CREATE TYPE stringlist IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(4000);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN stringlist DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       stringlist := stringlist();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       c1.COLUMN_VALUE AS t1_c1,
       t2.col1 AS t2_c1,
       t2.col2 AS t2_c2
FROM   table1 t1
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE( split_string( t1.col1 ) ) c1
       CROSS JOIN
       TABLE( split_string( t1.col2 ) ) c2
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t2
       ON ( c2.COLUMN_VALUE = t2.col1 )
```

**Output**:

```
ID T1_C1 T2_C1 T2_C1
-- ----- ----- -----
 1 PC1   F1    V1   
 1 PC1   F2    V2
 1 PC2   F1    V1
 1 PC2   F2    V2
```

**Alternative 2**:

Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```
WITH bounds ( id, a, b, start_a, end_a, start_b, end_b ) AS (
  SELECT id, col1, col2, 1, INSTR( col1, ',', 1 ), 1, INSTR( col2, ',', 1 )
  FROM   table1
UNION ALL
  SELECT id, a, b,
         end_a + 1,
         INSTR( a, ',', end_a + 1 ),
         CASE end_a WHEN 0 THEN end_b + 1 ELSE start_b END,
         CASE end_a WHEN 0 THEN INSTR( b, ',', end_b + 1 ) ELSE end_b END
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_a > 0 OR end_b > 0
),
data ( id, col1, col2 ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         SUBSTR( a, start_a, CASE end_a WHEN 0 THEN LENGTH(a) + 1 ELSE end_a END - start_a ),
         SUBSTR( b, start_b, CASE end_b WHEN 0 THEN LENGTH(b) + 1 ELSE end_b END - start_b )
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT d.id,
       d.col1,
       d.col2,
       t.col2
FROM   data d
       INNER JOIN
       table2 t
       ON ( d.col2 = t.col1 )
```

Comment: Sorry for very late reply, Thanks for your response, your first solution is giving better time than my previous query. I will try with other options to measure timing

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of alternatives involving recursive subquery factoring:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 id, 'PC1,PC2' col1, 'F1,F2' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 id, 'PC1,PC3,PC4' col1, 'F2,F3,F4' col2 FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 'F1' col1, 'V1' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'F2' col1, 'V2' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'F3' col1, 'V3' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'F4' col1, 'V4' col2 FROM dual),
     -- end of mimicking your tables; see below for the rest of the query you'd need:
     t1_rcrsv1 (ID, col1, split_col1, col2, lvl) AS (SELECT ID, col1, regexp_substr(col1,'[^,]+',1,1), col2, 1 lvl
                                                     FROM   t1
                                                     UNION ALL
                                                     SELECT ID, col1, regexp_substr(col1,'[^,]+',1,lvl+1), col2, lvl + 1
                                                     FROM   t1_rcrsv1
                                                     WHERE  regexp_substr(col1,'[^,]+',1,lvl+1) IS NOT NULL),
     t1_rcrsv2 (ID, col1, col2, split_col2, lvl) AS (SELECT ID, split_col1, col2, regexp_substr(col2,'[^,]+',1,1), 1 lvl
                                                     FROM   t1_rcrsv1
                                                     UNION ALL
                                                     SELECT ID, col1, col2, regexp_substr(col2,'[^,]+',1,lvl+1), lvl + 1
                                                     FROM   t1_rcrsv2
                                                     WHERE  regexp_substr(col2,'[^,]+',1,lvl+1) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT t1a.id,
       t1a.col1 t1_c1,
       t1a.split_col2 t1_c2,
       t2.col2 t2_c2
FROM   t1_rcrsv2 t1a
       INNER JOIN t2 ON t1a.split_col2 = t2.col1
ORDER BY t1a.ID, t1a.col1, t1a.split_col2;

        ID T1_C1       T1_C2    T2_C2
---------- ----------- -------- -----
         1 PC1         F1       V1
         1 PC1         F2       V2
         1 PC2         F1       V1
         1 PC2         F2       V2
         2 PC1         F2       V2
         2 PC1         F3       V3
         2 PC1         F4       V4
         2 PC3         F2       V2
         2 PC3         F3       V3
         2 PC3         F4       V4
         2 PC4         F2       V2
         2 PC4         F3       V3
         2 PC4         F4       V4
```

The above query first of all loops through col1 first, and then loops through col2 before joining to the second table. However, you might find that it's faster to do the join earlier, after looping through col2 first - like so:

```
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 1 id, 'PC1,PC2' col1, 'F1,F2' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 2 id, 'PC1,PC3,PC4' col1, 'F2,F3,F4' col2 FROM dual),
     t2 AS (SELECT 'F1' col1, 'V1' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'F2' col1, 'V2' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'F3' col1, 'V3' col2 FROM dual UNION ALL
            SELECT 'F4' col1, 'V4' col2 FROM dual),
     -- end of mimicking your tables; see below for the rest of the query you'd need:
     t1_rcrsv1 (ID, col1, col2, split_col2, lvl) AS (SELECT ID, col1, col2, regexp_substr(col2,'[^,]+',1,1), 1 lvl
                                                     FROM   t1
                                                     UNION ALL
                                                     SELECT ID, col1, col2, regexp_substr(col2,'[^,]+',1,lvl+1), lvl + 1
                                                     FROM   t1_rcrsv1
                                                     WHERE  regexp_substr(col2,'[^,]+',1,lvl+1) IS NOT NULL),
     t1_rcrsv2 (ID, col1, split_col1, col2, lvl, t2_c2) AS (SELECT t1a.ID, t1a.col1, regexp_substr(t1a.col1,'[^,]+',1,1), t1a.split_col2, 1 lvl, t2.col2
                                                            FROM   t1_rcrsv1 t1a
                                                                   INNER JOIN t2 ON t1a.split_col2 = t2.col1
                                                            UNION ALL
                                                            SELECT ID, col1, regexp_substr(col1,'[^,]+',1,lvl+1), col2, lvl + 1, t2_c2
                                                            FROM   t1_rcrsv2
                                                            WHERE  regexp_substr(col1,'[^,]+',1,lvl+1) IS NOT NULL)
SELECT id,
       split_col1 t1_c1,
       col2 t1_c2,
       t2_c2
FROM   t1_rcrsv2
ORDER BY ID, t1_c1, t1_c2;

        ID T1_C1       T1_C2    T2_C2
---------- ----------- -------- -----
         1 PC1         F1       V1
         1 PC1         F2       V2
         1 PC2         F1       V1
         1 PC2         F2       V2
         2 PC1         F2       V2
         2 PC1         F3       V3
         2 PC1         F4       V4
         2 PC3         F2       V2
         2 PC3         F3       V3
         2 PC3         F4       V4
         2 PC4         F2       V2
         2 PC4         F3       V3
         2 PC4         F4       V4
```

You'd need to test both queries (plus the solutions that MT0 provided) to see which worked best for you.

N.B. You may want to convert the inner joins to outer joins if you want to return all the table1's split columns regardless of whether there's a match in table2 or not.